# Mysql bind: number of elements do not match

Tags: php, mysqli

I can't fathom where I went wrong on this instruction. I keep getting the warning that number of elements does not match the bind value.
I'm trying to validate a field for country where users can select the country they are registering from but whenever I run a test on xampp I get the warning whilst the information aren't sent to the database.

I'm not sure if my code is liable to sql injections since I'm new to php and mysql. If i remove the country function the form works properly. I think the error is from the html form so I'd rather not uploaded it here.

Here's the php code.

```php
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "db.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = $country = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = $country_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }
    

      // Validate Country
    if(empty(trim($_POST["country"]))){
        $country_err = "Please Choose a Country.";     
    } 
         else{
        $country = trim($_POST["country"]);
    }



    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, country) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password, $param_country);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_country = $country;
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($db);
}
?>.`
```

Comment: The error means the number of columns you are trying to insert and the values passed doesn't match. Check your db table to see if you missed any columns ?

Comment: I have a column name country, set to VARCHAR

Comment: This does not fix anything though

Comment: You really should simplify this code. There is no reason why it has to be so complex. If it is not to late try learning PDO instead of mysqli. It is much more simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of things:

1. Your check for input errors does not check if "country_err" is empty.
2. Your mysqli_stmt_bind_param only defines types for 2 fields, "ss", but you are passing in 3 fields so it should be "sss"

Comment: Wow, this was the perfect answer. Thank you